# Reading from FileStream and StreamRaeder differences with encoding?

Tags: c#, file-io, encoding

Due to problems with the file I want to read from (when it was opened with word when I tried to read the File.Open variant failed and I had to use FileStream + StreamReader to avoid that problem) I had to switch from using File.Open and using the resulting FileStream to read, to

```
using (StreamReader sourceStream = 
         new StreamReader(
              new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, 
                             FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite), 
              Encoding.Default))
```

And then using the resulting streamreader to read the file.

Now what I'm wondering is: As I'm now reading a char array and using an Encoding (Encoding.Default), is there anything in regards to Encoding that works different now to the variant I had before (before I used File.Open and then read a byte array from the FileStream). Thus do I have to be more cautious now in regards to encoding than I had to before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to use `StreamReader`? It is designed to read characters not bytes, that's why it takes an Encoding parameter.
You can just read directly from `FileStream` using `FileStream.Read` or `FileStream.ReadByte` methods.

UPD:

And `File.Open` static method have all the same parameters as 'FileStream' constructor. So can't you just pass the same parameters to that method?

```
public static FileStream Open(
    string path,
    FileMode mode,
    FileAccess access,
    FileShare share
)
```

UPD2:

You can read the following console application to see the differences. Just change filePath to any UTF8 encoded text file.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace FileReadTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = "d:\\utf.txt";

            Console.WriteLine("Reding using File.Open");
            using (var stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                int oneByte = stream.ReadByte();
                while (oneByte != -1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(oneByte);
                    oneByte = stream.ReadByte();
                }
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Reading using StreamReader");
            using (
                StreamReader sourceStream =
                    new StreamReader(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite),
                        Encoding.Default))
            {
                int oneChar = sourceStream.Read();
                while (oneChar != -1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(oneChar);
                    oneChar = sourceStream.Read();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used file containing "123abc" and it contains some marker bytes at the beginning for UTF8 encoding. The output will be even more obvious if you place some specific symbols like Russian or Chinese into this file.

Comment: good point. just tried and saw that it functions still with FileStream used directly (don't know why it failed at my first test maybe a writing error there). Although the original quesiton woiuld still be of interest ot me if the result is different for the same files.

Comment: One character can consist of more than one byte depending on the encoding. So if you read character array (the first case) you can get result that differs from reading byte array. The question is how you will convert obtained character to bytes and store it to array.

Comment: I tested your comment in the answer: yep doesn't matter if fileopen or filestream as long as fileshare is set accordingly (I had copied the filesrteam variant from another post on stackoverflow). so the difference is as I had feared the encoding problematic with multiple bytes for 1 character,... tnx